# Symfony and Lucene search

Tags: symfony1, lucene, jobeet

We are using sf 1.4 and doctrine.

I installed Lucene according to the Jobeet tutorial. And I've been
getting into some problems with it.

When I do the search without any values I get the complete table that
Lucene is working with.

If I do a search of a value that was previously inserted into the table it returns nothing

But

When I do the search with values recently inserted I get this error, in each field of
the table;

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
callback, class 'Doctrine_Collection' does not have a method
'getCedula' in /usr/share/php/symfony/escaper/
sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php on line 64
```

In each field it shows the field function like getNombres,getDate and
such.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your relationships. If you are expecting an row object and getting a doctrine collection this is usually the case. If you would like to post up your schema we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't see yout comment.

This is how I solved my problem

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d883623/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony/jointure-relation-1-n/

```
   <td><a href="<?php echo url_for('admins/edit?usuarioid='.$personass->getUsuarioid()) ?>"><?php echo $personass->getUsuarioid() ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $personass->getCedula() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $personass->getNombres() ?></td>
```